# Can I control the bucket that is used by elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-s3

I use the JDK API to deploy to elastic beanstalk.

I'd like to change the bucket that elastic beanstalk uses at the account level (for uploaded versions, logs, etc.) - is that possible?

I want to control the name of the bucket that the elastic beanstalk API generates, or to tell it to use a bucket that I have previously created.

---

Edit:

One of the reasons I was asking about this is that I didn't realise the generated bucket name was simple combination of [prefix] + [region] + [account number].  I didn't recognise my own account number, I though it was just a random suffix to guarantee uniqueness >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that bucket is used internally by Elastic Beanstalk to keep track of your application versions, logs etc. and cannot be changed.

Comment: Totally agree, but do you know if there is any specific documentation stating this? I know https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html this touches on the S3 integration, but I was hoping to get a little closer to the core functionality. I am currently trying to see if I can pass tags down to the S3 bucket on creation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987627